# JS - Em um mesmo objeto, uma chave pode passar um valor para outra chave?

Tags: javascript, objetos, arrow-functions

A função `createMenu` recebe `menu` por parâmetro, `order` recebe o `request` por parâmetro, esse `request` é atribuído a chave `consumption` que é um array, na chave `pay` quero acessar o array `consumption` e comparar com o `menu` e gerar um valor `total` para fechar a conta. O problema é na chave `pay`, não sei se estou acessando a chave `consumption` de forma errada ou se não tem como fazer desse jeito.

```js
const menu = {
  food: {
    'coxinha': 3.90, 'sanduiche': 9.90
  },
  drinks: {
    'agua': 3.90, 'cerveja': 6.90
  }
};

const createMenu = (menu) => {
  const myRestaurant = {
    fetchMenu: () => { return menu },
    order: (request) => {
      myRestaurant.consumption.push(request) 
    },
    consumption: [],
    pay: () => {
      let total = 0;
      consumption.forEach(e => {
        if (menu.food[e] !== undefined) {
          total += menu.food[e];
        }
        if (menu.drink[e] !== undefined) {
          total += menu.drink[e];
        }
      });
      total += total * 0.1;
      return total;
    }
  };
  return myRestaurant;
};

console.log(createMenu(menu).order('coxinha'));
```

Comment: Esse código possui muitos erros, por favor **leia com muita atenção** a documentação [MDN-Trabalhando com objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) e depois reformule o seu código.

Answer (score -1):

ao chamar o array "consumption" na função da propriedade "pay", é preciso deixar claro que ele pertence ao objeto "myRestaurant".

```
myRestaurant.consumption.forEach(e => { // Continua o código
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).